# Force Wordpress users to have IP Address on login?

Tags: wordpress

It would be really great if anyone could let me know if there was a way to force users to have an IP address in order to be able to log in to a wordpress site?

We have troublemakers coming on with hidden IP addresses, it would be very good to grant access only if they have an IP.

If anyone has any thoughts on this your input would be very appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "hidden IP address"?  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] should always return some value. It can be either real IP address or some proxy IP address. But it should not be empty.

Comment: Hi, in our case, yes somehow they are entering the site without revealing an IP, not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer:**

You can create a plugin (or add code to your site functions plugin) to check the login using either wp_authenticate_user or authenticate filters. I do exactly this to check IP visitor country:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Login Validation XYZ */
function mysite_authenticate($user, $password) {
  //  if ( some ip check is failed) { e.g.
  //  if (cca_visitor_NOT_from('US,CA')) { /* or*/
  if ( CCAgeoip::get_visitor_country_code() != 'US') { // bounce if not from US (see below)
    remove_action('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
    $user = new WP_Error( 'denied', __("<b>ERROR</b>: some error msg") );
  }
  return $user;
}
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'mysite_authenticate', 10, 3 );
?>
```

However it might make more sense to do at registration (the [registration errors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors) filter?) Or if you are only interested in visitors from specific countries then you may be able to check earlier still via webserver (e.g. .htaccess)  - more and caveats below.

**The long answer:**

It appears you are talking about trolls manually entering abusive comments rather than spambots and RPC.

You can validate IPs like this:

```
if ($someIPvar != '127.0.0.1' && filter_var($someIPvar, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE) !== false) {
 /* then its valid & not localhost or a private range*/
}
```

But this won't help as chances are they will use an anonymous proxy or VPN; and your server will identify a valid VPN/proxy IP address.

If (a big if) all legitimate visitors are from a few countries then blocking your site from others (htaccess) or restricting comments (WP login) could reduce troll comments by blocking those using proxies/VPNs with IPs outside your country. If this is a realistic option for you then:

**Ideally block at webserver.** Use [countryipblocks.net](https://www.countryipblocks.net/country_selection.php) to create an ACL list e.g. for htaccess (select allowed countries, select "htaccess allow") and paste into your htaccess. However, **if using a reverse proxy NGINX or CDN this may result in incorrect blocking/allowing**.

Script to [identify how IP environment variables are being set by your server](http://wptest.means.us.com/script-display-ip-environment-variables/). If this indicates 'REMOTE_ADDR' contains the correct IP for your browser then an htaccess check is probably okay. **Otherwise:**

You can install a GeoIP plugin and use it within the login code snippet above (it uses the [Category Country Aware Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-country-aware/) as an example). It is designed for content, not security, but does the job here. I'm the author, as its the only one I'm familiar with I'm shamelessly using as an example. Some plugins may not work with your server configuration (via link to script above). The CCA Plugin checks for Cloudflare identified country if present, then HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_REAL_IP' & 'REMOTE_ADDR' which should cover most configurations.

**Edit following comments; Cloudflare:**

janh makes a valid point about potential benefits of Cloudflare which I see you are using. Points to note:

**Cloudflare and IP Env Variables**: Depending on configuration you may find 'REMOTE_ADDR' contains a Cloudflare IP, and the visitors IP is in 'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'. My sites "on" Cloudflare use a CF approved host and BOTH 'HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP' and 'REMOTE_ADDR' contain the "real" visitors IP. Again this can be checked using linked script above. See also [mod_cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/technical-resources/#mod_cloudflare).

**Country identification:** Cloudflare can identify visitor country for you. CF Dashboard->Network and switch on "IP Geolocation"; if enabled then many plugins like mine will check this first as it saves processing on your server.

**Country blocking:**  You can block visitors from individual specified countries via the CF dashboard. There is no option (as far as I know) to allow only from specified countries. There is a whitelist option - bout I think that is to with allowing frequent requests to your server e.g. by CF itself.

Comment: Hi Scytale thanks for your thorough input that is really great. I will have a play around with a few of your ideas. Yes I was expecting that, once we force them to have an IP of some description, that they would use a VPN. In that case it's not ideal to block the IP because other users might also be using a VPN. I will have a go with some of your suggestions though, and hopefully one will do the trick. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi usernnnn thanks for the feedback. As you are using Cloudflare I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Every HTTP request has an IP address, but it can be different from the local IP address of the actual user if he uses a proxy.

You cannot really recognize proxies just by looking at the IP address. Some do send a special header (usually `X-Forwarded-For`) to let you know the IP address of the user they are proxying this request for, but others won't, and you cannot force them.

Most proxies are operated within data centers, so you could do a whois lookup of the IP and block the IPs server providers (especially cloud computing, as it's relatively cheap).

There are services out there that help with proxy detection (usually to help reduce fraud, see [maxmind](http://dev.maxmind.com/proxy-detection/), [ip2location](https://www.ip2location.com/ip2proxy-web-service)), but none of them are free.

If you are having trouble with bots rather than trolls, a service like CloudFlare can help a lot, but if it's real users, I'm afraid technical solutions won't help if they are dedicated.

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback that's great. Ok we are using Cloudflare, so I will look into ways to use that.